# Android: Changing background of a drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have a rounded corner drawable background for the comment activity layout in my app (layout_bg_round_corners):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/deep_orange"/>
    <corners android:radius="20dip"/>
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

The background of the drawable shine through as white. Instead, I want them to be black.

How can I set the background color for a drawable?

[image: comment]

This is how I have set the parent view's layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_bg_round_corners"
```

Comment: You mean the the background of the drawable's parent view? Just set that view's background color to black: android:background="#000000"

Comment: you cannot as you have to set the drawables parent view to the drawable, otherwise you will not get round corners and also the entire view will be black.

Comment: Then a layer-list drawable sounds like a plan. I'll post a sample.

Comment: Please do - i think that might work but if you can make it work, you will get my vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I've completely misunderstood you, layer-list drawable should do the trick :)

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/deep_orange"/>
            <corners android:radius="20dip"/>
            <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: perfect. It did the trick. Thanks. I will accept your answer after 3 minutes has elapsed.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you need to give black color to the relative layout, try this

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="#000000">
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/layout_bg_round_corners">
```

Comment: Also another possible solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in the layout xml add the tag android:background="*color code*"

OR you can set the background to a drawable  by replacing the color code with a drawable id.

Comment: That's what I have done - i have set the background to a drawable which reflects the deep-orange color. I cannot set black as an additional background color to my drawable.